# angular 4 typescript specifying variable types best practices

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working with TS in angular 4, and there are basically 3 places where I currently specify variable types:

1. On variable declaration.
2. When passing parameters to a function.
3. Function return type.

I'm a bit confused because I know that TS can infer the type in most cases anyway. So when is it good to specify the type and when is it redundant?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice you should as much as possible define the types. This will help TypeScript know exactly which type to expect on each situation and give you proper errors during compile time, which is the whole point of having a strongly typed language. If you don’t define the type some times TypeScript can just set it to be of the type “any” and it can postpone potential issues to run time. You don’t want that.

It also brings a lot more readability of the code. Someone looking at the code and immediately seeing if a parameter is of a specific type (or a property or a return type) it will tell the developer exactly what’s expected, instead of having to figure it out from the IDE or from a later stage in the code.

Imagine you’re sharing a piece of code with someone or on a platform without intellisense or with a poor one. By not defining the type you lose one of the biggest advantages of using a strongly typed language.